# multiple instance of autowired bean

Tags: spring

When a bean is autowired, does it create multiple instances of the class?

Here's an example;

```
public class ClassA {

  @Autowired
  private ClassB classB;

  public ClassB getClassB() {
    return classB;
  }

  public void setClassB(ClassB classB) {
    this.classB = classB;
  }

  // using ClassB in method 1
  public void useClassBmethod1() {
    // currently using autowired ClassB instance
    classB.doSomething();
  }

  // using ClassB in method 2
  public void useClassBMethod2() {
    // need a new instance of ClassB but through the same autowired bean
    ClassB classb = getClassB();
  }
}

public class ClassB {


  public void doSomething() {}
}
```

So my question is, does autowiring a bean know how to create a new instance of a bean when needed or this is left to the programmer to decipher?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on attribute scope of bean tag. If `scope="singleton"` which is by default then each time you will get single instance and if `scope="prototype"` then you will get different instances. And it doesn't depend on autowire.

```
 <bean class="ClassB" scope="prototype">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s03.html#beans-factory-method-injection

Answer (score 1):

By using `@Autowired` you instruct classloader to associate any class instance available in container to associate with the callee. You need to make sure that you have made an entry to instantiate the bean in your config file like `<bean id="test" class="xxx.Test" />`. Also you might want to check scopes too.

If you have multiple instances of same class define with different names then with `@Autowired` you need to provide specific name that you want to use with the help of qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

by default all beans are singleton so only one instance will be created, more about scopes http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection